# Spatstat Point Pattern Analysis for colocalization

Tags: r, image-processing, bioinformatics, spatstat, colocation

I am trying to do some cololcaization analysis, i.e. I want to show if one cell type tends to show up closer to another different celltype significantly in a microsopy image.

I tried to do this with R spatstat package I was able to visualize my dataset:

[image]

mypattern is one kind of cell and mypattern2 ist another kind of cell. When u look at the L-plots you can see that there is some kind of clustering as the curve is deviating from poission.

I thought about using nearest neighbor apporoach which is the nncross function in spatstat.
But how can I show now if this distance is random (two random point pattern) or significantly relevant? Does anyone has an idea? I saw a lot about simulations like Monte-Carlo but I have no idea how to begin coding...

I would be glad for any help!

Kind regards,
Hashirama

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The L function should not be used here because the data are highly inhomogeneous.

I suggest you combine the two point patterns into a single "marked" point pattern,

```
X <- superimpose(A=mypattern1, B=mypattern2)
```

Then estimate the spatially-varying densities of points

```
D <- density(split(X))
plot(D)
```

or the spatially varying proportions of each type of cell

```
 R <- relrisk(X)
 plot(R)
```

You can also use `segregation.test` or a contingency table of nearest neighbours (`dixon`).

See Chapter 14 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) and the help files for `relrisk`, `density.splitppp` and `segregation.test`.

Comment: Wow I feel really honoured that the main author of spatstat in person gave me tips. Thank you very much! I read chaoter 14 of the spatstat book, especially Chapter 14.4. On page 581 you introduce the method segregation.test but I am a bit confused about the output as the p-value does not change really with my data. However, I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302701/monte-carlo-test-of-spatial-segregation). Can you please help me about the test statistic of the Monte Carlo test?